# Is it "ask a question to someone" or "ask a question from someone"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Sometimes we inevitably need to use a preposition when using the phrase "ask questions", the passive voice being one example of such occasions (Those questions must be asked to/from the teacher, not the students). Is the right preposition "to" or "from"? Or neither? I once heard a native English teacher use the preposition "to".

P.S. I know that asking something "of" someone means a asking for a favor. That's not my question.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's "of" also after "ask a question".

Comment: Neither one is normal; _ask_ does require an addressee, since it's a speech verb, but it normally requires the Dative Alternation (i.e, we say _Ask him a question_ rather than *_Ask a question to/for him_). _Of_ is occasionally used, but it's formal and involves presuppositions about authority and social status. And of course the addressee need not be expressed, or even known (_You can ask all the questions you want when we get to the Information counter_).